# ko.utils.arrayMap with Associative JSON object

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am trying to loop over an associative JSON object using ko.utils.arrayMap(), but the function never enters the loop when the it is done in this manner. Can anyone suggest how I can get at these properties. Possible I'm using the wrong utility function for thisstyle of JSON?

http://jsfiddle.net/rVPBz/

```
var data = [
   {
      "job_id":"AM28200",
      "inspection":{
         "5":{
            "inspection_type_id":5,
            "inspection_type_name":"hydro",
            "display_name":"Requested",
            "html_name":"Hydro",
            "itp":"Stage H1. H2, H3",
            "1":{
               "dates":[
                  "2013-10-21"
               ],
               "inspectors":[
                  " "
               ]
            },
            "2":{
               "dates":[
                  "2013-10-21"
               ],
               "inspectors":[
                  " "
               ]
            },
            "3":{
               "dates":[
                  "2013-10-21"
               ],
               "inspectors":[
                  " "
               ]
            },
            "4":{
               "dates":[
                  "2013-10-21"
               ],
               "inspectors":[
                  " "
               ]
            },
            "5":{
               "dates":[
                  "2013-10-21"
               ],
               "inspectors":[
                  " "
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   },
   {
      "job_id":"AM28212",
      "inspection":{
         "5":{
            "inspection_type_id":5,
            "inspection_type_name":"hydro",
            "display_name":"Waived",
            "html_name":"Hydro",
            "itp":"Stage H1. H2, H3",
            "1":{
               "dates":[
                  "2013-10-21"
               ],
               "inspectors":[
                  " "
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   }
]

var InspectionDiary = function() {
    var self = this;
    self.jobs = ko.observableArray([])

    function Job(data){
        var self = this;
        self.job_id = data.job_id;
        self.types = ko.observableArray([])
    }

    function Type(data){
        var self = this;
        self.type_id = ko.observable(data.inspection_type_id);
        self.name = ko.observable(data.inspection_type_name);
        self.display_name = ko.observable(data.display_name);
        self.html_name = ko.observable(data.html_name);
        self.itp = ko.observable(data.itp);
        self.inspectors = ko.observableArray([])
        self.dates = ko.observableArray([]);
    }

    var jobs = ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
        var job = new Job(item);
        var types = ko.utils.arrayMap(item.inspection, function(item) {
            var type = new Type(item)
            type.dates = ko.utils.arrayMap(item.dates(), function(item) {
                return new Dates(item);
            })
            type.inspectors = ko.utils.arrayMap(type.inspectors(), function(item) {
                return new Inspector(item);
            })
            return type;
        })
        job.types(types);
        return job;
    });
    self.jobs(jobs);
}

 ko.applyBindings(new InspectionDiary())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ko.utils.arrayMap is designed to be used on an array, not for an object.

To loop through an object you can use the following function :

```
var objectMap = function(o, handler){
    var res = {};
    for(var key in o) {
       res[key] = handler(o[key])
    }
    return res;
};
```

As the [mapping doc](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/04/utility-functions-in-knockoutjs.html) says :

ko.utils.arrayMap, which executes a function for each item in an **array** and pushes the result of the function to a new array that is returned.

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rVPBz/2/)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the json does not contain arrays in the proper places. For example, inspection should be an array and it isn't. Since it looks like you aren't doing a lot of extra stuff in the viewModels, you could try this for an easier mapping from JSON to VMs: http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Comment: Thanks for the help! It makes sense now! Do you know of any way I could iterate over the objects instead?